# When using to the power of operator it isn't returning the correct value X**(1/N)

Tags: python, exponent

so I'm just doing a basic math problem and noticed that it is returning an abnormally long float rather than the clean answer I was looking for. I am trying to take the 5th root of 100,000. So in normal mathematical notation we would be doing 100,000^(1/5)=10; however, my code in python is returning 10.000000000000002. I've tried the following bits of code:

```
100000**(1/5)
```

And

```
100000**.2
```

I understand why this might not work perfectly for, say, 1,000^(1/3) because 1/3 is a never ending decimal; however, I would think it should work fine for 100,000 ^ (1/5). Not sure what I may be doing incorrectly. Any help or insight appreciated.

Comment: Do read the article @TwistedSim linked to:  floats are stored in a binary format, and 1/5 cannot be represented exactly in any finite number of binary digits (just as 1/3 cannot be represented exactly in any finite number of decimal digits).

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the floating point precision. The floats in Python are encode on 64 bits (on a 64 bits system). So, you have a maximum possible precision to represent number. If you want absolute precision, use fixed point with the [Decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

For further explanation, see this [article].(https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)